# Challenges accessing/working with Rails credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I've been trying to access the API keys I set up in the Rails encrypted credentials. I added the keys to the file with Vim, and double checked they did save properly.

I added `config.require_master_key = true` to my test, development, and production files in `config/environments`.

But when I try to use one of the API keys, it returns `nil`.

I have the credentials set up like this:

```
# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies.
secret_key_base: 1234567890

stripe:
  development:
    stripe_public_key: pk_test_1234567890
    stripe_secret_key: sk_test_1234567890

stripe:
  test:
    stripe_public_key: pk_test_1234567890
    stripe_secret_key: sk_test_1234567890
stripe:
  production:
    stripe_public_key: pk_live_1234567890
    stripe_secret_key: sk_live_1234567890
```

Then in the file I want to use it (`new.html.erb`) I'm trying to access the credentials within a script.

`const stripe = Stripe("<%= Rails.application.credentials.stripe.stripe_public_key %>")`

But it doesn't return anything.

I tried several other versions/syntax after digging through Stack Overflow and the Rails docs, but haven't gotten anything to work yet.

Also tried `const stripe = Stripe("<%= Rails.application.credentials.stripe[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe_public_key] %>")` but no luck with that either.

When I run the server, and view the script in Chrome Dev Tools, it just shows as `const stripe = Stripe("")`

Worth noting that when I run `rails credentials:show`, the credentials are printed to the terminal correctly, so they do exist. I must just be accessing them incorrectly.

Comment: Can you see your credentials when using `Rails.application.credentials.config` ?
My guess is that you have to use `Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_public_key]` or with env `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:stripe_public_key]` Since the environment comes first...

Comment: Thanks @DennyMueller

When I use just `Rails.application.credentials` it shows this in the Dev Tools: `const stripe = Stripe("#&lt;ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration:0x00007fbe5d5dee68&gt;")`

`Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_public_key]` displays an empty string

and `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:stripe_public_key]` throws an error: `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: `Rails.application.credentials` is jsut for debugging to check in the rails console if your keys are even loaded correctly... Its not supposed to be used in the view. Also you should debug this directly in the rails console or terminal and not through `js > html > erb > rails > ruby`

Comment: That makes good sense why I should not be debugging that way! Thanks for pointing that out. 

I used the console instead, and returned this:


`=> {:secret_key_base=>"1234567890", :stripe=>{:production=>{:stripe_public_key=>"pk_live_1234567890", :stripe_secret_key=>"sk_live_1234567890"}}}`

Comment: Does this yield anything in the rails console `Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe_public_key]` ?

Comment: No, just an error: `NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)`

Comment: `Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][Rails.env.to_sym]` ? If that returns an error... how about `Rails.application.credentials[:stripe]`?

Comment: That seems more encouraging. returning:

`=> {:production=>{:stripe_public_key=>"pk_live_1234567890", :stripe_secret_key=>"sk_live_1234567890l"}}`

Comment: Ahh ok... it only has the production key on your local machine? Because thats why `Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][Rails.env.to_sym]` is failing since `Rails.env.to_sym` most certainly is returning `:development` and this is a non existing key in your credentials...

Comment: Thanks! I thought that the dev key would be present based on what I've set up in the credentials. I have `config.require_master_key = true` in my `environment/development.rb` file, which I was under the impression would be enough to access those keys. Is the `development.rb` file where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You issue is that you set them up slightly wrong I believe `stripe: > development:` and the  next entry overwrites the `:stripe` key with `stripe: > test:` and finally with `stripe: > production:` so you only have entry. The correct setup pf the yml is `:environment > :stripe > ...`

Comment: That looks like it did it! I fixed the format of the yml, and now I'm getting the value back as expected. Thank you so much for taking the time to help with this! And in case anyone else comes across this, `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:stripe_public_key]` was correct once the yml was fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DennyMueller pointed out in the comments, the problem was that the 'stripe' key was overwritten in the file and only the last one ended up existing in the configuration.

It's anyway useful to point out that this is not the way Rails expects to manage credentials that depend on environment. Instead, you should have separate files `config/credentials/development.yml.enc` and `config/credentials/test.yml.enc`, which are generated by running

```
rails credentials:edit --environment development
rails credentials:edit --environment test
```

So each credentials file should not have the environment name as a key anywhere inside.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful too! I've split each of my credentials into separate environments as you suggested, and everything is running smoothly now.